# Can I say that something "goes down on the agenda"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

So, I know the expressions *high on the agenda* and *low on the agenda* but do not know how to say that something becomes high or low on the agenda.
Is it **goes down on the agenda** or **falls down on the agenda** or **falls on the agenda** or what?

Comment: I've quickly found internet examples using 'put / place / push (-ing) issue X higher on the agenda'.

Comment: Probably you should avoid "goes down on the agenda" because of the jokes that will ensue.

Comment: We often talk about reprioritisation leading to existing items [***slipping down** the agenda.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02EpYslFdc7G35BUdN-tvLIrNnUkQ%3A1586704865588&ei=4TGTXpLLI8qW8gLo0JrYAQ&q=%22slipping+down+the+agenda%22&oq=%22slipping+down+the+agenda%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7309.8074.0.9166.4.4.0.0.0.0.179.581.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.AJUxmmzyU8Q)

Comment: There is a conflict between using the `Up/Down` metaphor for priority and using the `Put down on the list` metaphor of being _tabled_ in the British sense, i.e, making it on to the list in the first place. _Something goes down on the agenda_ could mean either one in context.